# wordpress contact form 7 drop down selected populate value into input box

Tags: jquery, wordpress, drop-down-menu, contact-form-7

The problem I would like help solving is once a drop down value on contact form 7 has been selected for example "1" the input box next to it inserts a price in this example "1" should display "£11.99"

Full example as following

1 = £11.99 2 = £13.99 3 = £14.99 (anything above 3 will equal £14.99 up to 12)

```
Payslips Required
[select* payslips-required "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "9" "10" "11" "12"]
[text price]
```

Above is what I currently have. The only close thing I have come across is this. http://jsfiddle.net/erwin21/A8Nxp/246/

Also how would I use the above in conjunction with contact form 7 on Wordpress

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT

This is how the short code appears in HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/payslips/wp-content/themes/discover/js/jquery-1.5.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/payslips/wp-content/themes/discover/js/payslipprice.js"></script>

<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap payslips-required">
<select name="payslips-required" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select wpcf7-   validates-as-required" id="payslips-required" aria-required="true">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
</select>
</span>  

<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap price">
<input type="text" name="price" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7 text" id="price" />
</span>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updated to work with your example: http://jsfiddle.net/rgin/A8Nxp/353/

```
var map = [ '£11.99', '£13.99', '£14.99' ];

$('#choice').change(function(){
    var o = parseInt($(this).val()) < 3 ? $(this).val()-1 : 2;
    $('#other').val(map[o]).addClass('hidden');
});
```

---

<s>You mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/rgin/A8Nxp/352/</s>

```
$('#choice').change(function(){
    var selected_item = $(":selected", this).text()
    selected_item = parseInt(selected_item) < 3 ? selected_item : '4 and above';
    $('#other').val(selected_item).addClass('hidden');
});
```

Comment: Exactly what I required but do you know how I can this on the wordpress contact form 7 plugin as the drop down appears like the short code (see above) and I need it to be populated into the "price" short code?

Comment: That might actually require more information than what this question has. You might want to post another question with the generated HTML and other useful information.

Comment: I have updated the original post to show how it is generated. I have also tried to add your solution into a .js file and attach it to the header.php of my theme but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It could be a number of things. You used the wrong selector, the .js file wasn't loaded after jquery.js, etc etc. Here's an updated fiddle with the current html: http://jsfiddle.net/rgin/A8Nxp/354/

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the post to show how I am linking the jquery. In payslipsprice.js it is a direct copy of the what's in the fiddle. Any suggestions?

Comment: Which fiddle? The one on my answer doesn't use the same selectors as generated on your html. Use the fiddle I posted on my last comment. If that doesn't work, post a link to your actual work, there may be other factors that keep this from working.

Comment: I used the one you updated for the HTML generated in the comment and still no luck. The work is run on localhost so wouldn't be able to link you to the work

Comment: I'm afraid this is the extent of my help then. Without seeing your actual code, I don't have any idea what else could be wrong. I will say this, though, adding the scripts like that in wordpress is wrong. You might want to check the docs for `enqueue_script`.

Comment: Also, it's just a thought but did you add `$(document).ready(){});` in your payslip.js file? Also also, try putting the script after the html is generated. It's a long shot, but it might be the issue.

Comment: OH. MY. GOD. I've been using `$( function(){});` for so long, I couldn't see the problem right away. Change `$(document).ready(){});` to `$(document).ready( function(){ /* your code here */ });`.

Answer (score 4):

try this:

i just edited you fiddle and added some.

```
var price = ["£11.99","£2.99","£11.99"];    

$('#choice').change(function(){
        $('#other').val(price[parseInt($(this).val())-1]);
});
```

Comment: This doesn't when `$(this).val()` returns 3 and above.